# Python selenium error randomly occours: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium

An error randomly occours in my python selenium project, where i scrape data from websites. It fetches date, temperature, wind and rainfall. The script sometimes run normally, but other times the error pops up:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.141)

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

def job():
    url="https://pent.no/60.19401,11.09936"

    dates = "forecast-day-view-date-bar__date"
    times = "forecast-hour-view-hour-label"
    temps = "forecast-hour-view-weather-widget__temperature"
    winder = "forecast-hour-view-weather-widget__wind-speed"
    rainfalls = "forecast-hour-view-weather-widget__precipitation"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

    date = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(dates)
    i = 0
    
    for klikk in dates:
        date[i].click()
        i = i +1
        if i==len(date):
            break

    time = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(times)

    temp = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(temps)
    temp2 = temp[::2]
    temp3 = temp[1::2]

    wind = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(winder)
    wind2 = wind[::2]
    wind3 = wind[1::2]

    rainfall = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(rainfalls)
    rainfall2 = rainfall[::2]
    rainfall3 = rainfall[1::2]

    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    d = []
    e = []
    f = []
    g = []
    h = []

    #    
    for datoer in date:
        print(datoer.text)
        a.append(datoer.text)
        a.extend([""]*23)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns= ["Date"])
    print(df1)
        
    #
    for tider in time:
        print(tider.text)
        b.append(tider.text)
        
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns= ["Time"])
    #  
    for tempyr in temp2:
        print(tempyr.text)
        c.append(tempyr.text)
        
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(c, columns= ["Temp Yr"])

    for tempstorm in temp3:
        print(tempstorm.text)
        d.append(tempstorm.text)
        
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns= ["Temp Storm"])
    #   
    for windyr in wind2:
        print(windyr.text)
        e.append(windyr.text)
        
    df5 = pd.DataFrame(e, columns= ["Wind Yr"])

    for windstorm in wind3:
        print(windstorm.text)
        f.append(windstorm.text)
        
    df6 = pd.DataFrame(f, columns= ["Wind Storm"])
    #   
    for rainfallyr in rainfall2:
        g.append(rainfallyr.text)
        print(rainfallyr.text)
        
    df7 = pd.DataFrame(g, columns= ["Rainfall Yr"])
    df7 = df7.replace(r'^\s*$', "0.0 mm", regex=True)
      
    for rainfallstorm in rainfall3:
        h.append(rainfallstorm.text)
        print(rainfallstorm.text)
        
    df8 = pd.DataFrame(h, columns= ["Rainfall Storm"])
    df8 = df8.replace(r'^\s*$', "0.0 mm", regex=True)
    #
    tabell = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8]
    result = pd.concat(tabell, axis=1)

    result.to_excel("weather" + str(int(datetime.now().day)) + ".xlsx")

            
    driver.quit()
    
schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: not sure why u r looping a string to perform clicks => for klikk in dates, where dates'"forecast-day-view-date-bar__date";

Comment: ```selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException``` occur when your element was removed from the DOM. This mainly occur on a dynamic website where the page refreshes the data. From your code it can occur post gathering the element on any call to the WebElement. (.I ```click, text```)

Comment: There is no "easy" way to fix this. I have implemented a wrapper on top of selenium to avoid such thing and gather the new element. In your case, try to have the call to the element (```i.e text```) closer to the element being retrieved (```find_by..```).

Comment: @nic I have tried your tip, but the error still occours. Do you have a link for how to implement a selenium wrapper into python?

Answer (score 0):

what i am confused about its that you are looping through `dates`, which is a **string** in your code.

```
dates = "forecast-day-view-date-bar__date"
date = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(dates)

for klikk in dates:
    # 1st loop -> klikk = 'f'
    # 2st loop -> klikk = 'o'
    date[i].click()
    i = i +1
    if i==len(date):
       break
```

what i thought you could have done is, since you want to toggle all tab on the page.

```
dates = "forecast-day-view-date-bar__date"
dates = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(dates) # assign as dates not date

for date in dates:
    date.click()
```

and for your problem, it is exactly what @Nic Laforge said, moving these lines:

```
for datoer in date:
    print(datoer.text)
    a.append(datoer.text)
    a.extend([""]*23)
```

before your loops:

```
for klikk in dates:
    date[i].click()
    i = i +1
    if i==len(date):
        break
```

Comment: The simple fix was to change the time.sleep command to 60 seconds instead of 1. Weirdly enough, the error doesn't occur anymore.